# In what order does the sklearn implementation of GridSearchCV evaluate parameter combinations?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I've been looking and I can't seem to find the order of combinations by which [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) evaluates hyperparameters.

For the sake of this example, let us assume I am using the estimator `xgboost`. So, if I have a dictionary of parameters for it, as follows:

```
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1, 5],
        'gamma': [0.5, 1],
        'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]
        }
```

Per the documentation of [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html), the parameter order in the `XGBClassifer` for this example is:

```
max_depth
gamma 
min_child_weight
```

**Question** - What is the search order of the parameters? Is it dependent of the order of the `params` dictionary provided or the order by which the estimator (in this case `xgboost`) takes in parameters?

Any examples would be helpful.